# How to get month number from month string in Java?

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I've got this string

> 23/Gennaio/2014

and I need this other string

> 23/01/2014

I tried **using joda.time**:

```
DateTimeFormatter format =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ITALY);
DateTime instance = format.parseDateTime("23/Gennaio/2014");  
String month_number = String.valueOf(instance.getMonthOfYear());
```

But I get this exception:

> 01-06 13:31:55.341: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "23/Gennaio/2014"

What am I missing?

Comment: MMM means short form of a month e.g. JAN, FEB. What you want is the long form, MMMM.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to expect the month name in lower case (not sure why):

```
DateTime instance = format.parseDateTime("23/Gennaio/2014".toLowerCase(Locale.ITALIAN));
```

should work better.

Comment: First letter is lowercase because that is the [cultural norm for Italian](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Italian/Vocabulary/Day_and_Month). Ditto for French and some other Romance languages.

Answer (score 2):

**23/Gennaio/2014** is not a valid date string to be parsed.
Try **23/gennaio/2014** and try to parse it with "dd/MMMM/yyyy" format (add an **M**)

Answer (score 1):

why not pure java?

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatIn = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.ITALY);
 Date instance = formatIn.parse("23/Gennaio/2014");  
 SimpleDateFormat formatOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ITALY);

 System.out.println(formatOut.format(instance));

 String month_number = String.valueOf(instance.getMonth()); //DEPRECETDE USE CALENDAR
```

result is "23/01/2014"

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String dateString = "23/Gennaio/2014";


     Log.i("meenal","Date 2:"+localizeDate(dateString, Locale.ITALY));


}

private String localizeDate(String inputdate, Locale locale) { 

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatCN = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", locale);       
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


    try {
        date = dateFormatCN.parse(inputdate);

        Log.i("meenal", "Date:"+date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("meenal", e.getMessage(),e);
        return inputdate;
    }
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Comment: result will be 23/01/2014